Various types of Mudras that are used in pujas
What is a Mudra ? I have seen many upasakas make specific hand gestures while chanting mantras. How many types of Mudras are there and what are the uses of it. Can any householder use the Mudras to enhance their practice. What are the rules to use a Mudra? Also which spiritual texts mention the context of Mudras (Upanishad, Vedas, Puranas,etc.)

5 pancha mudra should be shown to kaalasha before forming abhesikha 1. Garuda 2. Gauh (Amrita mudra) 3. Sankha 4. Kadha 5. Padma mudras. on showing this infront kalasha, the water inside Kallasha gets santified. only with this water abhisheka to lord should be performed..

I think mudras are mentioned in hatha yoga padipika like granthas which is a book for ashtanga yoga it's not important if you prefer bhakti yoga over ashtanga yoga you can go to Iskcon for knowing how should I do Puja correctly if you want to do Puja of Radha Krishna else there are other book like Nitya-karm Puja prakash of Gita press in which very tough pujas(you won't understand it as in some places it states to chant some mantra but in kulrnav tantra it is denied to chant mantras taken from books or without initiation)for devi-devtas etc are written.
You should go with either vaishnavism or shaivism or your choice and meet a guru to avoid mistakes in Puja

Hatha Yoga Pradipika Pdf
Nitya karma Pooja prakash pdf
Vaishnav etiquettes pdf
